# python command equivalent to = operator

Tags: python, assign

Could anyone tell me if there is a command in python to assign values to variables other than the "=" operator?
Instead of writing x = 2, I would like to find a command (say "assign" for example) such that "assign(x, 2)" is equivalent to "x = 2".

Comment: You can use `locals()["x"] = 2`, or `setattr(cls, "x", 2)`, depending on whether it's a variable or an attribute you wish to set.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why you want to do this?  Seems to me like this could be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @mara004 You cannot reliably assign to the return value of `locals` (unlike `globals`, which can be done safely though rarely *should* you be doing that).

Comment: @chepner I thought whether to use locals() or globals() only depends on the scope in which you want to define the variable? What makes locals() unreliable, in your opinion?

Comment: @mara004 [The documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: `locals()` is free to return a temporary object or some other dictionary that won't update actual local variables, since the actual variables may be optimized in some way to make the function faster. With `globals()`, you're getting an actual runtime object representing the module. With `locals()`, you're asking the interpreter to construct a new object based on what variables it can see.

Comment: mara004: you are right this is a XY problem.
The "real" problem is to use "=" operator inside the "code" of the exec.
consider:
def function():
    x = []
    exec(code)
    return x
and let
code ='''
for i in range(3):
    x = x + [i]
'''
if I run function() I get x = []
--------------------------------------BUT------------------------------------
if I set
code ='''
for i in range(3):
    x.append(i)
'''
and run function() I get x = [1, 2, 3] which is what I want.
So it seems that the "=" operator is causing problems and I wanted to get rid of it by not using "=".

Comment: @LeonRios: It was not me who made the XY Problem comment - that was user 0x5453

Comment: @0x5453:mara004: The "real" problem is to use "=" operator inside the "code" of the exec. consider: def function(): x = [] exec(code) return x and let code =''' for i in range(3): x = x + [i] ''' if I run function() I get x = [] --------------------------------------BUT------------------------------------ if I set code =''' for i in range(3): x.append(i) ''' and run function() I get x = [1, 2, 3] which is what I want. So it seems that the "=" operator is causing problems and I wanted to get rid of it by not using "=". – 
León Jaime Bendayán Ríos
 20 hours ago   Delete

Answer (score 2):

In practice its better if we use '=' but running the following also does it:

```
globals().__setitem__('y', 2)
```

A variable name y with value 2 is created.

Comment: This works, thanks,

Comment: It's not necessary to use the private `__setitem__` implementation. Better do common dictionary index access instead: `globals()['x'] = 2`.

Comment: @mara004 That uses `=`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Whoops, you're right.

Comment: @LeónJaimeBendayánRíos If you want to do this to create variable variable names: Don't do it! There are appropriate data structures like a dictionary or a list for that.

Comment: @Matthias: ok, but can you do that without using "="?

Comment: @LeónJaimeBendayánRíos You can even do that [with](https://tio.run/##DYwxCoAwEAR7X7FdErTTQgK@JKTyLmgTwxEhIr49Xrkzw5anHlee1yK9Eyck6/wAEDa8phmPED/d3Hi3piltGBGWaCaQUyFcb8mgoHEcipy5Wv1wvf8) using "=".

Comment: @Kelly Bundy you are right. I have seen examples on internet doing what you say  but I cant do it on my PC. I dont know why. But with this little trick I can.